# PowerShell not loading assemblies for use when fired from command line or batch script

Tags: powershell, batch-file, .net-core, windows-10, clipboard

As stated in question, found a very weird bug in Powershell when running from command line or batch file.

Expected behaviour of PowerShell command like `Add-Type -AssemblyName` is to load assembly specified as the argument to that command and then we should be able to use that assembly for the next command we run, even when we do this process in batch script or command prompt.

But that doesn't work when we run this in batch file or command prompt:

```
@echo off && SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION ENABLEEXTENSIONS
net file 1>NUL 2>NUL
if not '%errorlevel%' == '0' (
    pushd "%~dp0" & powershell Start-Process -FilePath "%0" -ArgumentList "%cd%" -verb runas >NUL 2>&1 & popd
    exit /b
)
cd /d "%1" && set "ScptDir=%1"

PowerShell "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::Clear()"
endlocal && exit
```

OR

```
@echo off && setlocal
@pushd %~dp0 & fltmc | find "." && (powershell start '%~f0' ' %*' -verb runas 2>nul && exit /b)
whoami
:: PowerShell "Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::Clear()"
type NUL | clip.exe
popd && pause && endlocal && exit
```

These doesn't clear the Windows System clipboard contrary to what anyone would expect. Also tried `PowerShell "& {Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::Clear()}"`, but no change.

Any changes or workaround in this to make it work ??

Comment: Are you sure, when running as administrator that the same initiating users clipboard is available for clearing.

Comment: I am in administrators group that's for fact..

Comment: That is not what I asked.

Comment: Which user's clipboard does dotnet code clears, if I am(from administrator group) the logged in user and I fired the command without any specific <user> argument ??

Comment: Okay, let me put this another way, what happens, if you first include `Get-Clipboard`? i.e. ```%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe "Get-Clipboard; Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms; [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::Clear(); Start-Sleep -Seconds 3; Get-Clipboard"```.

Comment: It brings up the clipboard but there's nothing there, even if I just copied the sample text: VickyDev and hasn't cleared the clipboard since. So what are you trying to say, I am clearing some other user's clipboard, but this is my personal system and I am the only user besides the core system that's using it and I am already member of administrators group, all that doesn't matter when I run that command ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247424/discussion-between-vicky-dev-and-compo).

Comment: That is exactly what I thought may be happening Vicky Dev, hence my opening comment.

Comment: @Compo let's continue our discussion in chat as it seems to gonna take long, I already messaged you there

Comment: The question(s) all readers of this specific question will want an answer to, are **1.** Why are you elevating the batch file? **2.** Why are you clearing the clipboard with elevation? Maybe if you provide more context it would help us to better understand the overall goal.

Comment: Additionally, what is the purpose of ```pushd "%~dp0"``` then ```-ArgumentList "%cd%"```, when as soon as it's being "Run as administrator" you're using ```cd /d "%1" && set "ScptDir=%1"```. It seems to me as if you could just use `CD /D` or `PushD` with `"%~dp0."` and then, if necessary, ```Set "ScptDir=%CD%"``` without needing to use the initial `pushd` or the PowerShell `-ArgumentList` parameter at all.

Answer (score 0):

- The Windows clipboard is a *user-specific* feature.

  - A given clipboard instance is tied to a given user's *OS session* (window station, typically the desktop of the interactively logged-on user).
  - *All* locally executing processes launched in the OS session of a given user share the same clipboard - even if such processes impersonate *other* users. (By contrast, sensibly, the clipboards of the OS sessions of distinct users are distinct.)
- Thus, for a user's given OS session, regular and elevated (run-as-admin) processes use the same clipboard.

  - Whether elevation happens in the context of the *current* user account depends on whether that user is a member of a group with administrative privileges. If so, only a *yes/no* [UAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) dialog is presented, and, if confirmed, the elevated process runs with the same user identity.
  - However, as explained above, even if you used *different* credentials for elevation, the resulting process would still see the same clipboard.
- Setting or clearing the clipboard does *not* require elevation.

  - Note that clearing the clipboard with `[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::Clear()` and equivalent methods has no impact on the opt-in clipboard *history* feature available since Windows 10. That is, it clears only the clipboard's *current* content, not the previous copied entries that are already stored in the history.

---

- Therefore, your batch file *should* work, and it does when I try it.
- If you're simply looking to clear the current user's clipboard from a *batch file* (whether elevated or not), use the following (note: technically, this doesn't *clear* the clipboard but sets it to an *empty string*):

  ```
  type NUL | clip.exe
  ```

  - From *PowerShell*, a simpler alternative to `[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::Clear()` is to use `Set-Clipboard $null`, but note that in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, which supports only copying *text* to the clipboard, this too - like `type NUL | clip.exe` in a batch file - copies an *empty string* to the clipboard instead of clearing it.

Comment: Whilst I don't doubt your test mklement0, just be aware that the OP specifically told us that `Get-Clipboard` added prior to the `clear()` instruction was showing nothing, even though they'd previously sent a known string to it, and that string still existed after the commands had completed.

Comment: Thanks, @Compo. My answer is trying to make general statements that describe the _expected_ behavior. If VickyDev observes different behavior, they'll need to provide a [mcve] that would allow us to diagnose further. I'm asking innocently: do you see any problems with the statements in this answer?

Comment: No, I don't, if VickyDev was really trying to empty their own clipboard and invoked their batch file elevated, whilst logged into their own account, I would have hoped for the results you observed. My opening comment, and request to include the `Get-Clipboard` commands from the PowerShell command(s) was to determine if they were reporting a "weird bug in Powershell when running from command line or batch file", or otherwise. If, as stated, the clipboard is showing something other than the known entry, which they confirmed, their problem is not with `clear()`, but with the user/elevation part.

Comment: Understood, @Compo. Let's see what they come back with; hopefully this answer provides some conceptual guidance on what to expect.

Comment: @Compo & @mklement0: I don't know if this is gonna clear the deep hole of confusion that this question has gone down to, I also do realize that there are things at play here subtly which I didn't know, but I can say this, when I open an elevated powershell window, and run `whoami` it says my Username and when I `Open Terminal` without elevation and run `whoami` it says the same, my Username. Also when I run any Powershell or Batch/CMD script in elevated mode and then do `whoami`, it gives out the same user, my Username, is this something that you didn't see or expect from my Q @mklement0 ?

Comment: @VickyDev, everything you describe I do expect and it is consistent with what this answer states. if you use the same user account for elevation as that of the calling process, both processes should share the same clipboard, and that is the behavior I am seeing. If you don't, we'll need more information to diagnose this - unexpected - behavior.

Comment: Furthermore I only know this method of `whoami` to check whether the User that's active is me or not, after doing some research, even after elevation or self-elevation inside script. I don't know how to force a User session such that after elevation it grabs the session of that user, so you guys are gonna need to shed some light on that and also show me how can I test this better to clear the questions raised here. So, in short, let me know how can I get more info to resolve this state of ambiguity? What specific commands I need to run to get that ?

Comment: And I know that without elevation and Powershell code we can surely clear the clipboard, I have done that in my other batch scripts, but my main concern as mentioned in the question is why it doesn't add assembly-package or why it's not clearing the clipboard thro' powershell command fired inside self-elevated batch script. Is it evidently something wrong in my System's user config or a first-encountered bug in some edited situation ?

Comment: I just ran a slightly different code again, but it didn't clear the Windows System clipboard again, I have added the code to Question, so to continue on the recent concern, if these Users after elevation are same i.e. my Username, then I am compelled to conclude that there is something wrong with Powershell in clearing the system clipboard, also let's not forget that from Windows 10 it's a multi-entry clipboard, and it's not being cleared by batch code `type NUL | clip.exe` as well. If it's a shared clipboard, it should be able to be cleared by admin-elevated code right ?

Comment: @VickyDev, I realized that I introduced a distraction: it doesn't matter whether the elevated process uses the same user account or not, because what matters is whether the process was launched from the same _OS session_ (window station) - please see my update. If `type NUL | clip.exe` _also_ doesn't clear your clipboard, then the problem isn't PowerShell-specific. Also, from the behavior you observe you cannot infer that the assembly  not getting loaded must be the problem. If the assembly hadn't loaded, you would have seen an _error message_.

Comment: @VickyDev, the bottom line is: On a vanilla Windows 10 system, I expect your code to work, for the reasons explained, and it does work for me. Maybe there's something in your system's configuration that causes your system or an undiagnosed error condition. In the absence of further information or a [mcve], we won't be able to help you.

Comment: @VickyDev, I just noticed that you referred to a _multi-entry clipboard_ - are you referring to the opt-in clipboard _history_ feature that Windows 10 offers? `[System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::Clear()` has no effect on this history, it only clears the _current_ content. Ditto for the simpler alternative, `Set-Clipboard $null`, and `type NUL | clip.exe` - as noted in the update, the latter doesn't technically _clear_ the clipboard, but copies an _empty string_ to it. The same applies to `Set-Clipboard $null` in PowerShell (Core) 7+, which supports copying _text_ only.